# How to delete datanode from hadoop clusters without losing data

Tags: hadoop

I want to delete datanode from my hadoop cluster, but don't want to lose my data. Is there any technique so that data which are there on the node which I am going to delete may get replicated to the reaming datanodes?

Answer (score 3):

What is the replication factor of your hadoop cluster?
If it is default which is generally 3, you can delete the datanode directly since the data automatically gets replicated. this process is generally controlled by name node.
If you changed the replication factor of the cluster to 1, then if you delete the node, the data in it will be lost. You cannot replicate it further.

Comment: suppose i have 4 node and i want to delete 2 of them, is my data which is on deleting datanodes are gonna replicated to rest of the two datanodes automatically.....

Comment: you have 4 nodes and you have deleted one. this means there are 3 nodes left and each node contains same data since replication factor is 3. when you delete one more node,  the name node is not able to create a slot for 3rd replica. So, it will keep complaining about that and it will permanently try to bring them to the expected replication factor.The HDFS system has a parameter, replication factor, which tells the namenode how replicated each block should be. Until the system manages to replicate each block as many times as specified by the replication factor, it will keep trying to do that.

Comment: that means i will not lose my data right, and one more thing can we change the replication value to 2 into hdfs-site.xml after deleting the 2nd node out of 4 node..

Comment: yes. your data will be there but with only two replicas. And yes you can change the replication value.

Comment: The site address provided helps you in this. https://sites.google.com/site/hadoopandhive/home/how-to-change-replication-factor-of-existing-files-in-hdfs

Comment: Thank You very very much

Answer (score 0):

1. Check all the current data nodes are healthy, for these you can go to the Hadoop master admin console under the Data nodes tab, the address is normally something link http://server-hadoop-master:50070
2. Add the server you want to delete to the files `/opt/hadoop/etc/hadoop/dfs.exclude` using the full domain name in the Hadoop master and all the current datanodes (your config directory installation can be different, please double check this)
3. Refresh the cluster nodes configuration running the command `hdfs dfsadmin -refreshNodes` from the Hadoop name node master
4. Check the Hadoop master admin home page to check the state of the server to remove at the "Decommissioning" section, this may take from couple of minutes to several hours and even days depending of the volume of data you have.
5. Once the server is shown as decommissioned complete, you may delete the server.

> **NOTE:** if you have other services like Yarn running on the same server, the process is relative similar but with the file `/opt/hadoop/etc/hadoop/yarn.exclude` and then running `yarn rmadmin -refreshNodes` from the Yarn master node